# retrieve sql record from webservice and view on textbox

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, textbox

i am creating a web app in which i want to see my record on different textboxes

```
[{"attendee1":"o","attendee2":"p","totalmale":"2","totalfemale":"2","unit1":"o","unitd1":"o","unit2":"o","unitd2":"o","unit3":"o","unitd3":"o","unit4":"o","unitd4":"o","unit5":"o","unitd5":"o","remarks":"o"}]
```

this is how my records are coming from `webservice` when i supply a parameter(`(string id)`) how i need to retrieve the record and show the record on my textbox with the help of `AngularJS`

this is my `js` file

```
$http.get('/frmattendencerptqed.asmx/getuprec', {
        params: {
                  id: $scope.updateparam.comsonvinid
                }
  })
```

now what i need to do when i want to print the records in different textboxes

my textboxes are in  input field 
`<input type="text" ng-model="attendee1" />`

this is how all my textboxes are

i need your help what i need to do when i want to show the record on my textboxes

Comment: can u show all your text boxes

Comment: all the textboxes are in input field all are same like

`<input type="text" ng-model="attendee1" />`

Comment: so which value you want to show in the text box from your result?

Comment: the values which are coming from my webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the data you provided i made small example for you.in this you need to assign your result to a scope variable like below

```
$scope.something=your result;
```

from this fetch your value and assign to your model,here i am  taking attendee1 and assigning to model

```
$scope.attendee1=$scope.something[0].attendee1;
```

like this you need to give what ever you want from that result.
[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hL5u1IJFrkwziCm9MNpC?p=preview)